# PineScript request.sequrity() performance

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a pretty complex logic, that calculates about 5 UDT objects for each bar. I'm executing this logic in another timeframe with request.security.

It works correctly, but my question is: what is the best way to return values (from the performance point of view!) - each value return separately or all values in one array.

Best regards,
Andrew

Code example:

```
indicator("My script")

type myType
    int    value1
    int    value2
    int    value3
    string value4
    string value5
    string value6
    bool   value7

calculate_v1()=>
    myType object1 = myType.new(...)
    myType object2 = myType.new(...)
    myType object3 = myType.new(...)
    myType object4 = myType.new(...)
    myType object5 = myType.new(...)
    [object1, object2, object3, object4, object5]

calculate_v2()=>
    myType[] arrayOjbect = array.new<myType>()
    arrayOjbect.push(myType.new(...))
    arrayOjbect.push(myType.new(...))
    arrayOjbect.push(myType.new(...))
    arrayOjbect.push(myType.new(...))
    arrayOjbect.push(myType.new(...))
    [arrayOjbect]


[object1, object2, object3, object4, object5]  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", calculate_v1())
arrayObject = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", calculate_v2())
```

What is the best to use from the performance point of view: `calculate_v1()` or `calculate_v2()` ?